# 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++

Не работает код. Необходимо считать данные с файла(матрица размерностью 256х256) и потом применить муравьиный алгоритм(после считывания нужно указать базу для алгоритма, на ней и ломается). Если считывать матрицу размерностью 10х10 то все ок. 
Матрица выглядит следующим образом(3х3):
1 5 3
1 8 4
9 8 2
Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает...

```
/* Муравьиный алгоритм для решения задачи коммивояжёра */
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define N_MIN   3           // минимальное количество вершин
#define N_MAX   30          // максимальное количество вершин
#define ALPHA   1           // вес фермента
#define BETTA   3           // коэффициент эвристики
#define T_MAX   100         // время жизни колонии
#define M       200         // количество муравьев в колонии
#define Q       100         // количество
#define RHO     0.5         // коэффициент испарения феромона
// структура ПУТЬ (длинна, массив вершин, количество вершин)
struct WAY_TYPE {
int itabu;
int length;
int *tabu;
};

// вероятность перехода муравья ant в вершину to
double probability (int to, WAY_TYPE ant, double **pheromone, double **distance, int vertex) {
// если вершина уже посещена, возвращаем 0
for (int i=0; i<ant.itabu; ++i) if (to == ant.tabu[i]) return 0;

double sum = 0.0;
int from = ant.tabu[ant.itabu-1];
// считаем сумму в знаминателе
for (int j=0; j<vertex; ++j) {
    int flag = 1;
    // проверяем, посещал ли муравей j вершину
    for (int i=0; i<ant.itabu; ++i) if (j == ant.tabu[i]) flag = 0;
    // если нет, тогда прибавляем к общей сумме
    if (flag) sum += pow (pheromone[from][j], ALPHA) * pow (distance[from][j], BETTA);
}
// возвращаем значение вероятности
return pow (pheromone[from][to], ALPHA) * pow (distance[from][to], BETTA) / sum;
}

// основная функция алгоритма поиска
WAY_TYPE AntColonyOptimization (double **distance0, int vertex, int start) {
// инициализация данных о лучшем маршруте
WAY_TYPE way;
way.itabu = 0;
way.length = -1;
way.tabu = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * vertex);
// инициализация данных о расстоянии и количестве феромона
double **distance = NULL, **pheromone = NULL;
distance = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * vertex);
pheromone = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * vertex);
for (int i=0; i<vertex; ++i) {
    distance[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * vertex);
    pheromone[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * vertex);
    for (int j=0; j<vertex; ++j) {
        pheromone[i][j] = 1.0 / vertex;
        if (i != j) distance[i][j] = 1.0 / distance0[i][j];
    }
}
// инициализация муравьев
WAY_TYPE ants[M];
for (int k=0; k<M; ++k) {
    ants[k].itabu = 0;
    ants[k].length = 0.0;
    ants[k].tabu = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * vertex);
    ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu++] = start;
}

// основной цикл
for (int t=0; t<T_MAX; ++t) {
// цикл по муравьям
    for (int k=0; k<M; ++k) {
    // поиск маршрута для k-го муравья
        do {
            int j_max = -1;
            double p_max = 0.0;
            for (int j=0; j<vertex; ++j) {
            // Проверка вероятности перехода в вершину j
                if (ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu-1] != j) {
                    double p = probability (j, ants[k], pheromone, distance, vertex);
                    if (p && p >= p_max) {
                        p_max = p;
                        j_max = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            ants[k].length += distance0[ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu-1]][j_max];
            ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu++] = j_max;
        } while (ants[k].itabu < vertex );
        ants[k].length += distance0[ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu-1]][start];
        ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu++] = start;
    // оставляем феромон на пути муравья
        for (int i=0; i<ants[k].itabu-1; ++i) {
            int from = ants[k].tabu[i % ants[k].itabu];
            int to = ants[k].tabu[(i+1) % ants[k].itabu];
            pheromone[from][to] += Q / ants[k].length;
            pheromone[to][from] = pheromone[from][to];
        }
    // проверка на лучшее решение
        if (ants[k].length < way.length || way.length < 0) {
            way.itabu = ants[k].itabu;
            way.length = ants[k].length;
            for (int i=0; i<way.itabu; ++i) way.tabu[i] = ants[k].tabu[i];
        }
    // обновление муравьев
        ants[k].itabu = 1;
        ants[k].length = 0.0;
    }
// цикл по ребрам
    for (int i=0; i<vertex; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<vertex; ++j)
        // обновление феромона для ребра (i, j)
            if (i != j) pheromone[i][j] *= (1 - RHO);
}
// возвращаем кратчайший маршрут
return way;
}

// точка входа в программу
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");

double **D = NULL, *V = NULL;
int N = 0, A = 0;

// инициализация матрицы расстояний
/*while (N < N_MIN || N > N_MAX) {
    cout << "Введите количество вершин [" << N_MIN << ", " << N_MAX << "]: "; cin >> N;
}*/
    ifstream in("vert1.txt");
    in >> N;
V = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) in >> V[i];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            cout << V[i] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    ifstream in2("graph1.txt");
//cout << "Введите матрицу расстояний" << endl;
D = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * N);
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    D[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);
    for (int j=0; j<N; ++j) in2 >> D[i][j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << D[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    in.close();
    in2.close();
// инициализация баз агентов
while (A < 1 || A > N) {
    cout << "Введите базу для агента: "; cin >>A;
}

for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    if(V[i]==A){
        A = i;
        break;
    }
}


// запускаем алгоритм
WAY_TYPE way = AntColonyOptimization (D, N, A);


// выводим результат
    ofstream out("Path.txt");
    out << way.length <<' '<<endl;
    out << V[way.tabu[0]];
for (int i=1; i<way.itabu; ++i) out << " -> " << V[way.tabu[i]];

    out.close();
//cout << "Длина пути: " << way.length << endl;
//cout << "Путь: " << V[way.tabu[0]];
//for (int i=1; i<way.itabu; ++i) cout << " -> " << V[way.tabu[i]];

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример хоть и компилируется (это уже достижение), но сложно воспроизвести - нет как минимум файлов graph1.txt и vert1.txt, а также не понятно, какие данные вводить.

Comment: Ссылки на файлы.
https://yadi.sk/i/Ac0fB4Q0sSoLN
https://yadi.sk/i/eepkWrp4sSoLr
На входе количество вершин и название вершин(в файлах), в ручную вводим базу.
На выходе минимальный маршрут и его длина. Это задача коммивояжера решенная с помощью муравьиных алгоритмов.

Comment: у Вас в 39 строке (`if (flag) sum += pow (pheromone[from][j], ALPHA) * pow (distance[from][j], BETTA);` ) from равен -1. Поэтому и падает.

Comment: Где информация о дебаге, на какой строчке валится? Ответ на этот вопрос в таком виде будет бесполезен для любых других читателей, поэтому -1.\

Comment: А почему вы не используете тривиальный отладчик?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

(Одна и возможных причин) Там где у вас идет `// Проверка вероятности перехода в вершину j`, переменная `j_max` сначала устанавливается в  -1, затем, если вероятность не будет удовлетворена, остается в -1, и дальше используется как индекс массива в `ants[k].length += distance0[ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu - 1]][j_max];`.

```
        ...

            int j_max = -1;
            double p_max = 0.0;
            for (int j=0; j<vertex; ++j) {
            // Проверка вероятности перехода в вершину j
                if (ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu-1] != j) {
                    double p = probability (j, ants[k], pheromone, distance, vertex);
                    if (p && p >= p_max) {
                        p_max = p;
                        j_max = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            ants[k].length += distance0[ants[k].tabu[ants[k].itabu-1]][j_max];
        ...
```

Comment: Это круто, что Вы такое заметили, но отвечая на подобный бесполезный кому бы то ни было, кроме спрашивающего, вопрос, Вы способствуете захламлению ресурса вопросами и ответами, не несущими никакой пользы пользователям ресурса, а только усложняющими поиск решения ошибки.

Comment: @Arkady, вы правы конечно же. Наверное стоит пометить вопрос к удалению.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в строке:
     ... if (p && p >= p_max)...
изменил ее на     if (p >= p_max) и все стало нормально

Comment: учитывая, что p это double, очень интересно.